How to test an already deployed contract within scripts folder in hardhat?
I am trying to deploy two smart contracts using hardhat's scripts folder, and I am trying to attach the addresses of the deployed contracts to test them directly in my test folder. But since the ethers.js got an update and migriated from v5 to v6, I can not use "ethers.getContractFactory" anymore. A little bit of help would be appreciated.
Fallowing code block is from my scripts folder:
const {ethers} = require("hardhat")
require("dotenv").config({path: "/home/ardakl/blockchain-tutorials/hardhat/.env"})

async function main() {
    const contractFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory("StarDucks")
    console.log("Deploying...")
    const contract = await contractFactory.deploy(process.env.INITIAL_TOKEN_AMOUNT)
    await contract.waitForDeployment()
    console.log("contract deployed to: ", await contract.getAddress())

    const [deployer, addr1] = await ethers.getSigners();
    const contractFactory2 = await ethers.getContractFactory("TokenSale")
    console.log("Deploying...")
    const contract2 = await contractFactory2.deploy(1, deployer.address, contract.getAddress())
    await contract2.waitForDeployment()
    console.log("contract2 deployed to: ", await contract2.getAddress())

    //The code for getting the tokens from deployer address to TokenSale contract
    //...
}

and here is the code for testing:
const { expect } = require("chai")
const { ethers } = require("hardhat")
require("dotenv").config({path: "/home/ardakl/blockchain-tutorials/hardhat/.env"})

describe("StarDucks", () => {

    let starDucks, tokenSale;

    before("Get the signers and contracts", async() => {
        
        //attach StarDucks Token contract
        const StarDucks = await ethers.getContractFactrory("StarDucks")
        starDucks = await StarDucks.attach("0x1613beB3B2C4f22Ee086B2b38C1476A3cE7f78E8")

        //attach TokenSale contract
        const TokenSale = await ethers.getContractFactrory("TokenSale")
        tokenSale = await TokenSale.attach("0x851356ae760d987E095750cCeb3bC6014560891C")
    })

    it("Should not have any tokens in my deployer account", async() => {
        expect(starDucks.balanceOf("0xf39fd6e51aad88f6f4ce6ab8827279cfffb92266")).to.equal(0)
    })
})

But since I can not use getContractFactory anymore, I don't know how I can test
my already deployed contract. Can anyone help?
